# libGDX how do you draw on the top left corner of the screen when you are using a viewport and moving the camera

Tags: java, libgdx

```
public OrthographicCamera camera;
Viewport viewport;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch, 1920, 1080, camera);
    viewport.apply();
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
    camera.update();
```

then I move the camera with my mouse with this code

```
Vector3 v = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    camera.unproject(v);
        camera.position.set(v);
        camera.update();
```

everything works fine except I have some text I want to draw on the top left corner of the screen. I use camera.combined and it draws it on the original screen but it doesn't follow where I move the camera. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent question, I created a method to return a Vector3 which is relative to the screen position. I'm not sure if there is a built in way to do this or easier way but here is my code below. Good luck on your program me.

```
public Vector3 relativeVector(float x, float y,OrthographicCamera c){
    return new Vector3(x+c.position.x-c.viewportWidth/2,y+c.position.y-c.viewportHeight/2,0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This totally helped me.

Comment: @CodeCamper don't forget to thumbs up and mark as the answer.

Comment: That one is a performance killer. It creates a new vector3 object every time you call it. Better make the Vector a field an just set it to the values.

Comment: @laubed what about multi-threading? the only reason I opted to just create a new Vector3 is because I was worried that I was starting to access it from other threads.